# That IllegalMonitorStateException...thread not owning the object? Can't be, there's only one

Tags: java, multithreading, semaphore, illegalmonitorstateexcep

I have this class, which is a basic approach to a file locking utility (doesn't interact with the locks from the OS tho). The idea is to have a static HashMap which stores pair of references to File objects that are used by the application with binary semaphores. Upon first access to a new file the pair is stored into the variable.
The problem is that the .wait() line throws IllegalMonitorStateException, and I can't understand why, because I've created a project to test this class with only one thread, so it's impossible that the thread accessing the method doesn't own the object, isn't it?

```
public abstract class FileLocker {

    private static final HashMap<File, Semaphore> locksMap = new HashMap<>();

    public synchronized static final void getLock(final File file) {
        if (!FileLocker.locksMap.containsKey(file)) {
            FileLocker.locksMap.put(file, new Semaphore(1, Boolean.TRUE));
        }
        try {
            FileLocker.locksMap.get(file).wait();
        } catch (final InterruptedException e) {
            SysLogger.log(e, "ERR0", SysLogger.Level.CRASH);
        }
        if (file.isDirectory()) {
            for (final File f : file.listFiles()) {
                if (f.isDirectory()) {
                    FileLocker.getLock(f);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public synchronized static final void releaseLock(final File file) {
        if (file.isDirectory()) {
            for (final File f : file.listFiles()) {
                if (f.isDirectory()) {
                FileLocker.releaseLock(f);
                } else {
                FileLocker.locksMap.get(file).notify();
                }
            }
        }
        FileLocker.locksMap.get(file).notify();
    }
}
```

My intention was that the methods weren't synchronized, but since I started receiving this exception, I changed them to synchronized so they theoretically make sure that the thread entering them owns the resources used, but it's not working, the same exception arises.

Exception trace: 
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalMonitorStateException
    at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Object.wait(Object.java:503)
    at org.lsp.io.files.FileLocker.getLock(FileLocker.java:18)
    at org.lsp.main.Main.main(Main.java:9)

Called with

```
FileLocker.getLock(Paths.get("default.xml").toFile());
```

Comment: We need to see the calling code and the stack trace.

Comment: THis is a FAQ.  You wait while synchronized on an _object_ instance.  There can be 1000s of synchronized blocks but only one thread.

Comment: The methods are `synchronized` already @Gray so it is not the same question of your duplicated suggestion I think.

Comment: You need to read the answer @Jorge.  To use wait and notify you must be synchronized *on that specific object instance*.  In this case, you need to be synchronized on whatever the `get(file)` method returns.

Comment: Oh true, I'm dumb, I was synchronizing on the whole HashMap instead of the particular object. Thanks.

Comment: @JorgeAntonioDíaz-Benito technically you are synchronizing on the `class` instance, not the HashMap.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`FileLocker.locksMap.get(file).wait();`

should be

`FileLocker.locksMap.get(file).acquire();`

`wait` in this case is waiting on the Object monitor.  Since you are not synchronized on the semaphore ie:

```
Semaphore s = FileLocker.locksMap.get(file);
synchronized(s){
     s.wait();
}
```

you get your exception.  The `acquire` is offered by Semaphore and handles that synchronization for you.

**Note** You'll also run into the same situation with `notify()` instead of `release()`